# Removal of atypical images from a time series NDVI sentinel-2 Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2, time-series

I'm new to GEE.
How can I automatically remove by scanning sentinel-2 NDVI images from a collection of images, which contain outliers in their time series by taking into account the before and after image; Knowing that if the average of the two NDVI images (before and after) is greater than the atypical image, it will be eliminated? The final collection of images would be visualized in an NDVI - Sentinel-2 temporal graph.

IMPORTANT:
I cannot use metadata filter on sentinel-2 (% clouds) or cloud masking.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are probably so many things here.
A simple quick say will be

- is that for point or polygon?
- have you filtered the cloud percent for sentinel 2, then how much? (Doing this is important)
- Did you apply cloud masking?
  These two things alone can change that outlier.
  If that still persists even after playing with the above two, then masking anything below some value can also help.